# Finding next/previos item and setting as current item

Tags: c#, linq, collections

All,

I have a List that is bound to something.

Let's say I have a current index of i.  Now, I delete from the List several items (which may or may not be next to each other).  If I wanted to reset the current index to be either the next item after the delete (or if there is no next item, then the last item, assuming there are any items left) then what would be the best way to accomplish this without too much enumeration.

Basically, what I'm stuck with is it seems I need to figure this out before performing the delete and reference the new object somewhere, but I can't seem to do this without enumerating through several lists and bogging down my application.

```
List<Object> MyCoolList;
List<Object> ItemsIWillBeDeleting;
Object CurrentItem;

//For simplicity, assume all of these are set and known for the following code
int i = MyCoolList.IndexOf(CurrentItem);
Object NewCurrentItem = null;
if (MyCoolList.Any(a => MyCoolList.IndexOf(a) > i && !ItemsIWillBeDeleting.Any(b => b==a)))
{
    NewCurrentItem = MyCoolList.First(a => MyCoolList.IndexOf(a) > i && !ItemsIWillBeDeleting.Any(b => b==a));
    ItemsIWillBeDeleting.ForEach(a => MyCoolList.Remove(a));
    CurrentItem = NewCurrentItem;
}
else (if MyCoolList.Count > MyCoolList.Count)
{
    NewCurrentItem = MyCoolList.Last(a => !ItemsIWillBeDeleting.Any(b => b==a))
    ItemsIWillBeDeleting.ForEach(a => MyCoolList.Remove(a));
    CurrentItem = MyCoolList.Last();
}
else
{
    MyCoolList.Clear(); //Everything is in MyCoolList is also in ItemsIWillBeDeleting
    CurrentItem = null;
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this with Linq, but I'm struggling to find it.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Linq and Indices are not friends.

Comment: Okay.  I think I figured it out.  I just use Enumerator and NextItem (or whatever it's called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private ICollection<MyCoolClass> _someCollection

public void DeleteAndSetNext(IEnumerable<MyCoolClass> IEDelete)
{
    bool boolStop = false;
    MyCoolClass NewCurrent = _someCollection.FirstOrDefault(a =>
        {
            if (!boolStop) boolStop = IEDelete.Contains(a);
            return boolStop && !IEDelete.Contains(a);
        });
    foreach (MyCoolClass cl in IEDelete)
    {
        _someCollection.Remove(a);
    }
    CurrentMyCoolClass = NewCurrent ?? _someCollection.LastOrDefault();
}

MyCoolClass CurrentMyCoolClass
{
    get;
    set;
}
```